# Winforms new form instance in class not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to maximize a form from a class file but when I make a new instance of the form in the class nothing happens. I have spent a long time searching for an answer and did not find anything. This is the code I have in the class.

```
public void maxForm() //code from the class
{
    Options options = new Options();
    options.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; //not working
}
```

This is the code I have in the form.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //code from form
{
    Class1 class = new Class1();
    class.maxForm();
}
```

If I do the same code but for a different form it will work. It acts like its being blocked.

Comment: A Form is a class, so why do you need another class to do something to the form?

Comment: Based on your comment on Backs' answer, it seems that you expect creating an instance of something allows you to change another instance of the same type. `Options` is a type, and `options` holds a reference to an instance of `Options`. Imagine the type is a type of car: a Ford Mustang. Now, you create two instances of the Ford Mustang (you buy two from the dealership). You damage one car, does the other car change to reflect the damage to the first? No, because they are different cars (instances). They are the same type (Ford Mustang), but different instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I make a new instance of the form

That's your problem right there. You don't want a *new* instance, you want *the* instance that already exists.

If your `button1` is part of your `Options` form, then just do this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //code from form
{
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Or if, as you say, you need to maximize it from a different class (why?), then you can do something like this:

```
public void maxForm(Options options) //code from the class
{
    options.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //code from form
{
    Class1 class = new Class1();
    class.maxForm(this);
}
```

Comment: Yes I know I can do that I want it specifically from the class which is a different file.

Comment: Then you need to pass the instance of your open form. Maybe something like `maxForm(this)`.

Comment: I updated my answer with code for that, but it does sound fishy - why would you create a class just to maximize the form? Do you have some other requirements for that class?

Answer (score 4):

Don't you need to show form?

```
Options options = new Options();
options.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
options.Show();
```

Comment: @Joseph Perhaps an instance of the form is already shown, but `Options options = new Options();` creates a new instance. You could show them both side by side, in fact.